# Playstore: app shows wrong localizations

Tags: android, localization, google-play, beta

My Android app contains string.xml files for Swedish, English, Norwegian, Dutch and Finnish.

After uploading my app for Beta, the Playstore shows me that there are way more localisations (81!):

Why does this happen? In my earlier releases this was never the case

[image]

Comment: The dropdown should show which localisations you have

Comment: that's the problem yes, i doesn't shows alot more than that